# Laravel Lumen | get single values from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, lumen

I have a problem for like 4 hours.

```
 $getrank = DB::table('users')->select('codes')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->get();
```

with `var_dump($getrank);` I see whats in the array.

So I got this:

```
array(6) {
    [0] => object(stdClass)#62 (1) { 
        ["codes"]=> int(584)
    }
    [1] => object(stdClass)#64 (1) { 
        ["codes"]=> int(117) 
    } [2] => object(stdClass)#65 (1) { 
        ["codes"]=> int(88) 
    } [3] => object(stdClass)#66 (1) {
        ["codes"]=> int(66) 
    } [4] => object(stdClass)#67 (1) { 
        ["codes"]=> int(53)
    } [5] => object(stdClass)#68 (1) { 
        ["codes"]=> int(37)
    } 
}
```

But I want them seperated.
I tried a lot!

In the end I thought this could be my answer:

```
echo $getrank[0]['codes'];
echo $getrank[1]['codes'];
echo $getrank[2]['codes'];
echo $getrank[3]['codes'];
echo $getrank[4]['codes'];
echo $getrank[5]['codes'];
```

But no.

I want a ranking, and I just need the first 5 ([0]-[4]). What else can I do?
In the end I want every value as a string!

Comment: Hints: Take a look at `array_slice()` and at `array_map()`.

Comment: Ok, I got it seperated! Thanks! But now I want dem as a string!

Comment: So you got the first 5 codes inside an array? Or where are you at right now?

Comment: I have an Array. The Array read the column 'codes' in my table in the database. Then the Array sort them (desc). Now I want the first 5 (the highest values) as single strings so I can use them to create a Ranking!

Comment: $getrank = DB::table('users')->select('codes')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->take(5)->get() ?

Comment: It worked. Im not that smart, but I still need them as strings.

Comment: $getrank = DB::table('users')->select('codes')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

        $test = '';

        for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++) {
           $test .= $getrank[$i]->codes;
        }

        echo $test;

This is 1 String. I need 5

Comment: try to change the fetchMode before you run the query.DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now by reading your comments I understand what is the result you expect.

```
$getrank = array_map(
    function ($user) { return $user->codes; },
    DB::table('users')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->take(5)->get()
);
```

Does that get you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `pluck()` (or `lists()`, alias of `pluck()`) method for this.

```
$codes = DB::table('users')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->take(5)->lists('codes');

echo '<pre>';
foreach($codes as $key => $code) {
    echo 'code '.$key.': '.$code.PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

[Documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results)

Comment: Its the same for me like:

        for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++) {
   $test = $getRanks[$i]->codes;
   print_r($test);
  }

But the problem is, it looks like that: 584117886653
Its 1 String! I need 5

Comment: @MarcJansen It looks like one string because you've printed them out all one after the other, without any spaces or commas or anything. Take a look at my edit and you'll see 5 individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add toArray(), this will convert result from database to array, so you can use the code you've provided at the end of your question

```
 $getrank = DB::table('users')->select('codes')->orderBy('codes', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
foreach($getrank as $rank) {
echo $rank['codes'];
}
```

And if you want to cast codes value to string, it is just `echo (string) $rank['codes'];`